# unable to populate form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp

I am taking inputs in the main form which consists of a checkbox.
Before submitting the form i am showing a popup to confirm the submission.

I am unable to populate the checkbox field on the popup

```
var target = jQuery ('div#confirm_popup div.content');
```

code for populating the popup:

```
target.find('randomCheckboxMain').html(form_table.find('#randomCheckbox:checked').val());
```

here i am finding the check box in main form and then fetching its value and populating the pop up.

this is my main form checkbox, it is part of table with id="form_table"

```
<table id="form_table">
....
....
<tr>
    <td class="field_head">checkh:</td>
    <td>
        <html:checkbox property="prop" name="randomCheckboxMain" value="yes" disabled="true"></html:checkbox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

this is my popup field

```
        <tr>
            <td class="head">checkValue:</td>
            <td class="randomCheckbox"></td>
        </tr>
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: try changing #randomCheckbox:checked to ".randomCheckbox:checked"

Comment: no, still not working

Comment: what is form_table ? what is target ? Cant you paste full code ?

Comment: form_table is my main table which contains my checkbox

Comment: i am finding randomCheckbox in form_table

Comment: but you searching randomCheckbox in pop up

Comment: in my first code...i am searching randomCheckBox and setting its html with the checkbox value in popup

Comment: Put the required html and JS buddy

Answer (score 0):

you use of `class` in `<td class="randomCheckbox"></td>`

So :

change :

```
.html(form_table.find('#randomCheckbox:checked').val());
```

To :

```
.html(form_table.find('.randomCheckbox:checked').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a class in your td, but you have id in the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
target.find('.randomCheckbox').html(
      form_table.find('[name="randomCheckboxMain"]').val());
```

Give a ID or class to the checkbox to check easily if it is checked.